# How does php fileperms function return filetype?

Tags: php

I've learned that fileperms function return file type and file permissions but I'm having a hard time trying to understand the file type part.

when I used it on a .txt file it returned the following (after converting it to octal) 100666
and I know that the last 4 digits are the permissions so the file type here is the remaining digits which are 10, but 10 means that the file is a Symbolic link which it isn't because it is text file which should be considered as a regular file which should be a zero.
so what's the problem here and am I not supposed to get 00666 as output?

Comment: Why do you think regular file is zero? From `stat(2)`: `S_IFREG  0100000  /* regular */`

Comment: Symlink would be `12`. But `fileperms()` follows links and returns the permissions of the target file, so you'll never get that type.

Comment: so is this information wrong?
The first digit of the output of the fileperms() function in PHP represents the file type.

The possible file types are as follows:

Regular file: 0
Directory: 4
Symbolic link: 10
Block device: 6
Character device: 2
FIFO: 1
Socket: 12

Comment: Where do you find that? I don't see it in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php)

Comment: It's in the first hex digit, not the first octal digit. There's sample code in the above documentation that uses `$perms & 0xF000`.

Comment: 12oct = 10dec, maybe you used the wrong number base? If the docs say "the first digit", does that mean binary, octal, decimal or perhaps hex digit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UNIX-like operating systems, file types and permissions are represented as a bit-mask. The fileperms function returns this bit-mask as an integer. When you convert it to octal, you get a number like 100666, which can be dissected as follows:

The last three digits (666) indeed represent the file permissions.
The leading digits (100) represent both the file type and some additional flags.
The 10 in 100666 is not actually 10 in decimal; it's 10 in octal, which is 8 in decimal. It represents a regular file in UNIX permissions. Symbolic links have the octal 12 (or 10 in decimal), not 10 in octal.

So, the 100666 can be broken down like this:

1. 100 in octal (or 64 in decimal) indicates it's a regular file.
2. 666 in octal indicates the file's permissions (rw- rw- rw-).

Here's how you could isolate the permission bits and the file type bits:

```
$perms = fileperms('/path/to/your/file.txt');
$perm_octal = substr(sprintf('%o', $perms), -4); // Get the last 4 digits
$perm_bits = $perms & 0777; // Isolate permission bits
$type_bits = $perms & 0170000; // Isolate type bits
```